# Best way, how to assign voice command to event / method in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

in Visual Studio I´m creating application which use speech recognition for application control.

I´d like to ask you for help about what is the best way how to assign voice command to method.

I´m using Grammar Builder and Choices:

```
//Create Grammar Builder with Choices
 GrammarBuilder slovnik = new GrammarBuilder();
 slovnik.Append(new Choices("stop", "go"));
```

And If I´d like to assign one word from the choices to (voice command) to method (for example - showing Message Box) - In event handler I´m using if command:

```
void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "stop")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Some message, that the voice command works");
            }
        }
```

My question is - Is the If clause the best way how to join word / phrase from grammar to method / event or is there any better (cleaner) solution how to do that?
I´m using *C#* and *System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine*.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this.

First off, create your own `VoiceCommandAttribute` derived from the [`Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) class. It should have a constructor that takes a command name a stores it in the `string` field. The command name should be accessible via a property.

Then when your app starts you can iterate over all/some classes and their methods, retrive their attributes using reflection and make a dictionary where keys are command names from `VoiceCommandAttributes` and values are [`Delegates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) created from [`MethodInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx).

And lastly, in `SpeechRecognized` event handler you can lookup the word/phrase in the dictionary and invoke the delegate.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think using case can do the trick too.

```
void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {       
  string speech = e.Result.Text;       
    switch(speech)   
   {            
  case: "stop":          
 //do what you want           
  break;      
   }    
 }
```